# Do you need to do any further closing on an FileOutputStream when using Bitmap.compress()?

Tags: android, bitmap

Most of the examples I have seen online have something similar to:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(someFilename);
someBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

Is any additional work needed to close the stream and ensure that it was flushed to the disk properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should definitely call close() on the stream :)

Comment: The docs for close on the FileOutputStream say 
"Closes this stream. Implementations of this method should free any resources used by the stream. This implementation does nothing."  Does it really do nothing?  Should I be using a different kind of stream?

Comment: It's just the documentation inherited from OutputStream which indeed does nothing. You should definitely call close().